# How to stabilize a crack in wood?

Tags: repair, wood, screws, crack

I am working on my first wood product. I am completely new to this. The following happened:
[image]

My question is: **How do I stabilize this crack?**

Can I fill something into the hole so that the crack doesn't get any worse?

Comment: as rlc707 stated - you can countersink. However the stresses that might be applied to this - it will eventually split all the way down. Sometimes what is done is a large hole is drilled to end the splitting - when going lengthwise , it does not fix the original split but prevents it from walking further down the board. In your case you might try this at the end of the split - to limit the walk. This will weaken the connection as well which might cause that end piece to split off.

Comment: To merge your unregistered and registered user accounts, make sure you're logged in with the registered account, then click on the `contact us` link at the bottom of the page, then `I need to merge user profiles` from the dropdown and follow the instructions. You'll need to provide a link to the unregistered account profile. It might take a few days for the request to be processed (it's the weekend ATM).

Comment: I would add that although you can stabilize the crack, even with a pre-drill and countersink, a screw that close to the end of the board is likely to crack again anyway, particularly if it's carrying any load.

Comment: polyester resin can be ideal for this kind of repair

Answer (score 3):

Put glue-ca or wood glue in now, back out the screw and then predrill and lightly countersink so the screw will hold but not force wood apart.

Comment: I would add that you should disassemble, then glue and clamp tight until glue is cured. Then reassemble with appropriate pilot hole, countersink, fastener, and torque.

Answer (score 3):

The rule with splits or breaks like this is

1. Apply wood glue
2. Clamp the pieces

Don't skip #2 or you'll have wasted the glue. Clamping forces the glue into the wood, and it will be a stronger bond when cured, than the wood alone would be.

I would remove the screw, glue, clamp, and then take a drill bit the size of your screw head and chamfer the hole (just rev the drill and press lightly to let the drill cut a bevel where the head will sit). The chamfer should ensure it doesn't crack when added again.